# scipy.optimize slower when passing arguments to function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using Scipy's `minimize` method for a function which requires extra parameters in its definition. `minimize` allows you to pass optional arguments into your functions for this reason, for an example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

def func(x, a, b):
    # calculate function using a,b

def func_grad(x, a, b):
    # calculate gradient using a,b

x0 = np.random.rand(20)
min_args = (np.random.rand(20), 2)

opt.minimize(func, x0, args = min_args, method="L-BFGS-B", jac=func_grad)
```

Alternatively, one could declare the arguments as global variables and access them through the functions that way:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

def func(x):
    # calculate function using a, b

def func_grad(x):
    # calculate gradient using a, b

x0 = np.random.rand(20)
a, b = np.random.rand(20), 2

opt.minimize(func, x0, method="L-BFGS-B", jac=func_grad)
```

In my case, `minimize` is running as many as 10000-20000 iterations in total. Interestingly, the second code snippet runs about 10 seconds faster, with the only change being the arguments in the first code snippet are instead global variables. This surprised me as I know Python passes variables by reference, which should be essentially instantaneous. Is there something specific to Scipy's `minimize` method that makes using arguments inefficient in this case?

Comment: It'd be great for reproducibility if you could fill those commented-out parts in!

Comment: Although it would be very difficult for me to fill in the commented parts as it pertains to my code, I will try testing this on simpler code to see if it is reproducible and edit my post shortly.

Comment: Unfortunately I am having trouble replicating my issue in a simpler example, yet I am still consistently seeing a ~10 second discrepancy between the two methods in my code. I am at something of a loss for ideas at this point; I will try to profile my code.

Answer (score 0):

How is large is the 10s relative to the total run time.

When using the `args`, the call (to both the objective and jacobian) is essentially:

```
In [300]: def func(x,a,b):
     ...:     print(x,a,b)
     ...:     return 0
     ...:         
In [301]: args = ('a','b')    
In [302]: func(10,*args)
10 a b
Out[302]: 0
```

I wouldn't expect a large difference, compared to a global approach, but wouldn't be surprised to see a minor difference.

```
In [306]: def func0(x,a,b):
     ...:     return x+a+b
     ...: def func1(x):
     ...:     return x+A+B
     ...: A, B = np.arange(1000),2

In [307]: timeit func0(0,*(A,B))
7.64 µs ± 18.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [308]: timeit func1(0)
6.74 µs ± 24.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Comment: The total runtime is about 30s, 40s when passing through arguments. The difference of 1us would only account for ~.01s after 10000 iterations, so something else is up. I'll have to run more tests.